# Is it possible to prevent k8s secret of being empty (zero bytes)?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

Is it possible to configure k8s in a way that empty secrets are not possible?

I had a problem in a service that somewhat the secret got overwritten with an empty one (zero bytes) and thereby my service malfunctioned. I see no advantage of having an secret empty at any time and would like to prevent empty secrets all together.

Thans for your help!

Comment: What version of Kubernetes do you have ?

Comment: I am on 1.16.15 but plan to upgrade to 1.17.15 soon

Comment: If you have Kubernetes `1.19` or higher, you will be able to create [immutable Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#secret-immutable).
In Kubernetes `1.18` it's also available but the `ImmutableEphemeralVolumes` feature gate must be enabled.

Comment: Nice that kubernetes will support that, but immutable is not solving my problem of empty secrets.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not a simple answer to implement, as best I can tell what you are looking for is an [Admission Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/), with a very popular one being [OPA Gatekeeper](https://open-policy-agent.github.io/gatekeeper/website/docs/)

The theory is that kubernetes, as a platform, does not understand your business requirement to keep mistakes from overwriting Secrets. But OPA as a policy rules engine allows you to specify those things without requiring the upstream kubernetes to adopt those policies for everyone

An alternative is to [turn on audit logging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/) and track down the responsible party for re-education

A further alternative is to correctly scope RBAC Roles to actually deny writes to Secrets except for those credentials that are known to be trusted